# Where should I start reading My Hero Academia after season 5

Tags: my-hero-academia

My Hero Academia just finished season 5 and I wanted to go on with the story and so I wondered where do I start reading the manga after season 5.

Answer (score 2):

I just checked by myself and it continues with the chapter 258, if others want to know.